# FireMonkey Application with Multiple Monitors

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, multiple-monitors

I need to get the Screen Scale for the monitor my application is being displayed on. The multi-platform run-time `TPlatFormServices` has a service called `IFMXScreenService` that returns the Screen Scale (`GetScreenScale`).

The problem is it only returns it for the primary monitor. I need to get it for whichever monitor my application is being run on.

Below is my C++ code for getting the `IFMXScreenService`. How do I modify it to get the screen service for my active monitor?

```cpp
if (TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXScreenService)) == true)
{
  pScreenService_ = TPlatformServices::Current->GetPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXScreenService));
}
```

Comment: FireMonkey does not support what you are asking for. There is no per-monitor `IFMXScreenService` interface. You are going to have to use platform-specific APIs to get what you want. For instance, on Windows, getting the `HWND` of your FireMonkey Form from `FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND()` and then passing that `HWND` to the Win32 API `MonitorFromWindow()` and `GetMonitorInfo()` functions, and then calculating the scale yourself from that info.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I just cheated under Windows and added the following routine to my base form class:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TFormBase::GetScaleFactor()
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

double TFormBase::GetScaleFactor(void)
{
    double fScale = 0.0;
    #ifdef WIN32
    TPoint objTopLeft = TPoint(Left,Top);
    HMONITOR hMonitor = MonitorFromPoint(objTopLeft,MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL);
    if (hMonitor != NULL)
    {
        DEVICE_SCALE_FACTOR nScaleFactor;
        if (GetScaleFactorForMonitor(hMonitor,&nScaleFactor) == S_OK)
        {
            fScale = static_cast<double> ((static_cast<int> (nScaleFactor))) / 100.0;
        }
    }

    if (fScale == 0.0)
    {
        fScale = ScreenService->ScreenScale;
    }
    #else
    fScale = ScreenService->ScreenScale;
    #endif

    return fScale;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how in C++ Builder, in Delphi I do this as follows

```
function GetScreenshotZoom(APoint: TPoint): Single; overload;
var
  Monitor: HMonitor;
  DpiX, DpiY: Cardinal;
begin
  if TOSVersion.Check(6, 3) then
  begin
    Monitor := Winapi.MultiMon.MonitorFromPoint(APoint, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
    GetDPIForMonitor(Monitor, MDT_Default, DpiX, DpiY);
    Result := DpiX / StandardDpi;
  end
  else
    Result := 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uses Winapi.ShellScaling, Winapi.ShlObj, Winapi.MultiMon;

function GetScreenScale(sc:integer): Single;
var
  Monitor: HMonitor;
  Scale: DEVICE_SCALE_FACTOR;
  p:TPoint;
begin
  result:=1;
  p.X:=Screen.Displays[sc].BoundsRect.Left;
  p.Y:=Screen.Displays[sc].BoundsRect.Top;
  Monitor:=MonitorFromPoint(p,MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL);
  if (GetScaleFactorForMonitor(sc,Scale)=S_OK) then
  begin
    result:=(100.0 / Integer(Scale));
    if result=0 then
      result:=1;
  end;
end;
```